# Modification after camera ready abstract is submitted

Tags: conference, presentation, abstract

I recently got an abstract accepted by a linguistics conference as oral presentation.
However, I didn’t have time to make all the modifications according to reviewers’ comments. Now the deadline for camera ready abstract is over, and I have already made the submission.

Is it possible that I present the modified analysis on the presentation?

- small differences such as further explanation on the evidence.
- it won’t be an entirely different talk.

Comment: Do you mean that you plan to give a talk that deviates from the original abstract you submitted? Does it make it an entirely different talk, or are these just small differences?

Comment: It won’t be an entirely different talk, but with small differences such as further explanation on the evidence.

Answer (score 1):

> It won’t be an entirely different talk, but with small differences such as further explanation on the evidence.

It may depend on a community, and I'm not familiar with the linguistics community, but I think you worry too much. It is understood that you keep doing your research, and the conference is an opportunity to report on the newest findings.

If you report on behalf of other people (e.g. your team or collaboration) then indeed you should get their approval for the changes. But the conference organizers will be only more happy if you present a more mature version of your work.

It's not unusual to introduce small modifications to the talk. On some conferences, you actually resubmit the abstract just before submitting the actual talk, and possibly once more, when submitting the proceedings. Each of these is a chance to make small improvements, or fix mistakes.

But, if you feel uncertain, contact the organizers.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion